# What is the fastest way to compare entries from two different pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have two lists in form of pandas DataFrames which both contain a column of names. Now I want to compare these names and return a list of names which appear in both DataFrames. The problem is that my solution is way too slow since both list have several thousand entries.
Now I want to know if there is anything else I can do to accelerate the solution of my problem.

I already sorted my pandas dataframe by alphabet using "df.sort_values" in Order to create an alphabetical index so that a name in the first list which starts with the letter "X" will only be compared to entries with the same first letter in the second list.

I suspect that the main reason my program is running so slow is my way of accessing the fields which I am comparing.

I use a specific comparison function to compare the names and access the dataframe elements through the df.at[i, 'column_title'] method.

Edit: Note that this specific comparison function is more complex than a simple "==" since I am doing a kind of fuzzy string comparison to make sure names with slightly different spelling still get marked as a match. I use the whoswho library which returns me a match rate between 0 and 100. A simplified example focussing on my slow solution for  the pandas dataframe comparison looks as follows:

```py
for i in range(len(list1)):     
    for j in range(len(list2)):  
       # who.ratio returns a match rate between two strings
       ratio = who.ratio(list1.at[i, 'name'], list2.at[j, 'name']) 
       if ratio > 75:
          save(i,j)       # stores values i and j in a result list
```

I also thought about switching from pandas to numpy but I read that this might slow it down even further since pandas is faster for big data amounts.

Can anybody tell me if there is there a faster way of accessing specific elements in a pandas array? Or is there a faster way in general to run a custom comparison function through two pd dataframes?

Edit2: spelling, addtitional information.

Comment: If you only want a list at the end of shared values, take the data out of the df, create two sets and get the intersection.

Comment: Your code suggests that you have a double-nested loop. This is also terrible for efficiency. If you want a df at the end, not a list, then do something like `df1 = df1[df1['name'].isin(df2['name'])]`

Comment: The problem is that I want to use my custom comparison function which returns me a "match rate" between two names. I don't want to miss a matching name because of a slightly different spelling. E.g Adam Mueller should match Adam Muller.

Comment: Sure. And the reason that you haven't included that requirement or the code that addresses it in the question is...? Please give a [mcve]

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. I see that the term "specific comparison function" could be misleading and interpreted as "==". Thank you for pointing this out. I made an edit to the original question to make this more apparent. I will add a repoducible example right now.